# after upgrade to php7 connection to mysql from php DB returns DB Error: extension not found

Tags: apache2, php, mysql

After upgrading from ubuntu 14.03 to 16.04. I cannot connect to mysql from php DB. The following code returns

```
<?php
    include_once('DB.php');    
    $conninfo = "mysql://xxxx:ppppp@localhost/ddddd";
    $db = DB::connect($conninfo);        
    if (DB::isError($db)) {
        print $db->getMessage();
        exit;
    } else {
        $result = $db->query("SELECT distinct did from selections where cid=6 order by did DESC;");
        while ($result->fetchInto($row, DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC)) {
            extract($row);
            print "$did\n";
        }
        $result->free();
    }
    $db->disconnect();
?>
```

DB Error: extension not found.

Note that from mysql, opened from the terminal, I see the contents of the table's column 'did'.

Following the advice of oerdnj from a similar post, I confirm that

1. php7.0-mysql package is installed
2. mysqli appears in phpinfo. Below is the result of phpinfo | grep mysqli
3. and listed below is the output for the ldd command

> php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -i mysqli
>   /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
>   mysqli
>   MysqlI Support => enabled
>   mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => On
>   mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
>   mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
>   mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
>   mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
>   mysqli.default_socket => no value => no value
>   mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
>   mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
>   mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
>   mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off
>   mysqli.rollback_on_cached_plink => Off => Off
>   API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql
>
> ldd /usr/lib/php/*/mysqli.so
>     linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc807a9000)
>     libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6cde88a000)
>     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055a1af509000)

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql extension is missing in php7 installation. Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858165/mysql-extension-is-missing-in-php7-installation-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Please also refer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1):

PHP offers multiple interfaces to interact with MySQL. One of those interfaces, the one containing functions like `mysql_connect()`, `mysql_query()` etc., has been marked as deprecated (meaning "this is outdated, don't use it anymore") for years and years. With the release of PHP 7, those old functions have finally been removed from PHP.

It looks like your database layer is using those outdated and now removed functions. You should replace them with one of the newer interfaces to MySQL that PHP offers, like `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `$conninfo = "mysql://xxxx:ppppp@localhost/ddddd";` to `$conninfo = "mysqli://xxxx:ppppp@localhost/ddddd";` and now it works. I don't understand why mysql worked in php5 but not in php7