# Mysql extension is missing in php7 installation. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, php, extension

I am having trouble enabling `mysql` in my `php-config`.

`apt-get install php-mysql` and `apt-get install php7.0-mysql` don't make a difference.

Also, the shared object is missing from the `php` extension directory.

Is there any way I could get the `mysql.so`?

Comment: if your using php7, the _php7.0-mysql_ version should be used only. Remove the other and see if it improves.

Comment: In ubuntu 16.10 :  /usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so  is provided by php7.0-mysql package.  Check /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, you should have : extension=mysqli.so

Answer (score 26):

On Ubuntu, I fixed this error by running

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

And then restarting my server (caddy, apache, nginx).

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37083448/3006854)

Comment: Couldn't get this to work on PHP7.1, Ubuntu 16.04 (mysql was still missing)

Comment: The error I got, which this information helped me fix:  "PHP is missing the MYSQL EXTENSION that WordPress needs".

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 I had to force it to use php7.0-mysql even though I'm actually  using php 7.3 (Wordress version 5.2)

Answer (score 5):

I'd assume you're talking about the (very) old style MySQL functions in PHP like `mysql_connect()` or `mysql_query()`. Those functions have been deprecated for years and years, and have finally been removed in PHP 7. Use the [mysqli extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or one of vendor-independent abstraction layers like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact question but related to a very specific version of Ubuntu on a Docker image. The trick was to update and install in the same RUN command.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. php7.0-mysql was the offending missing package(s) =)

Answer (score 0):

mysql extension was removed in PHP 7.

You should use mysqli or pdo_mysql instead.

If you still need to use mysql functions (eg. for legacy code support), you may compile the mysql extension manually.

Here's the procedure:  https://ckon.wordpress.com/2015/08/06/put-mysql-functions-back-into-php-7/

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli.so` is indeed flagged missing and seemingly NOT installed in 18.04. It appears to me the packages are broken because there is a `php-mysqli` and it is not installed while `php-mysql` is.

I was not able to install the `php-mysqli` package otherwise and it throws no errors in apt when I try, it just doesn't install anything.

However, I found `mysqli.so` in `/var/lib/php/modules/7.2/cgi/enabled_by_admin/`.

Add `extension=/path/here/to/mysqli.so` under your `extension=mysqli` in `php.ini` and you should stop throwing the `mysqli.so` missing error.

IMHO these packages are borked and it isn't entirely clear what provides `mysqli.so`, and won't work out of the box unless you enable the extension and set your path for the extension once you find it (you can use `dpkg-query -L` to see if `mysqli.so` is part of the package contents, and where it gets installed)

Answer (score -3):

If I understand correctly, installing LAMP stack should fix your issue. Try this guide

https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: Op want's help for mysql not the whole stack